# creating an image download link

Tags: php, wordpress

I use wordpress cms and I am working on a little script wherein visitor could upload image, resize and download. I am stuck in the download stage. I have already written most of the code but I am unable to connect these things together to make it work somehow. **First** among these is a resize.php which basically resizes the image and  creates a jpeg file. Here is some relevant snippet from my resize.php.

```
<?php  
       //normal validation stuff happens here
       //resizing stuff happens here

    //here is last part of the code that creates the resized image

    $filename = uniqid();
    $file = 'uploads/'.$filename.'.jpeg';   
    imagejpeg($new, $file, 80); 
    imagedestroy($new);
```

---

**Second** is a download.php. Here is a code in my download.php. If you see a lot of question mark in the code, that means I am sure that these are the codes I am missing.

```
// ????????????
    $FilePath = TEMPLATEPATH. '/resize/uploads/';  
    $final = $FilePath . $FileName;

    $size = filesize($final) ;
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"". $FileName ."\"");
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header("Content-Length: ". $size ."");
    header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
    header("Expires: 0");
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    echo (readfile($final));
```

---

**Third** is an html link I have currently on the template page, again question mark for missing code. If someone clicks the link they are supposed to get the newly created resized image file.

```
<a href="'.get_template_directory_uri().'/resize/download.php???????">DOWNLOAD</a>'
```

---

I hope you got the gist of my issue. I am having a hard time trying to figure out how these three will work together to create a download link for the recently resized image. While I am struggling for a solution myself, Please help me point out the mistakes and suggest corrections. THANKS.

---

**FINAL UPDATE** : After a few hours of effort, **I have this sorted now**. I did not realize earlier that the only thing I was missing was the `query string` and the `$_GET`. After I understood their role in this whole process everything was pretty easy. Later on when I downloaded the images they came out corrupt. How I sorted that I saved the corrupted files everytime, opened them up in notepad++ and checked for the error. Now my application is flawless. Of course the codes are drastically changed, now. Thanks to everyone for whatever bit of interest they took to help.

Comment: The HTML5 download attribute makes this so much simpler.

Comment: does not work in firefox and that attr is built mainly for modern browsers only, not scalable

Comment: Suggestion: you have three different declared `Content-Type` headers, and two different `Cache-Control` headers (you probably only want one of each). I don't think this will solve the problem, but it can't hurt.